# Let $A$ be a complete Noetherian local ring. What are the units of $A[[x,y]]/(xy-a)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Let $A$ be a complete Noetherian local ring with maximal ideal $m_A$ and residue field $k$. Let $R := A[[x,y]]/(xy-a)$, where $a\in m_A$. Any element $r\in R$ can be written uniquely as:
$$r_0 + xF(x) + yG(y),\qquad r_0\in A, F(x)\in A[[x]], G(y) \in A[[y]]$$
What are the units of this ring?

**Claim:** The units are precisely those $r$ such that in the expansion above, $r_0\in A^\times$.

I would appreciate if people could check the correctness of the following proof. This seems like a suspiciously simple proof of a natural claim which is suspiciously absent from many accounts of the ring $R$ (for example, in Wewer's "Deformation of Tame Admissible Covers of Curves", and various other papers on deformation of nodal curves) - So suspicious, in fact, that I wonder if the claim is false...

(Perhaps I'm being too cavalier with my manipulations of power series?... I don't know - something seems off.)

**Proof**: Note that $R$ is a local ring, with maximal ideal $m_R := (x,y,m_A)$ (and quotient field $k$). Consider the map 
$$\varphi : R\twoheadrightarrow R/m_AR =  k[[x,y]]/(xy)$$
Then this is a surjective homomorphism of local rings which sends $m_R$ to the maximal ideal of $k[[x,y]]/(xy)$. Thus, $r\in R^\times\iff \varphi(r)\in (R/m_AR)^\times$.

Hence, it suffices to show that the units of $S := k[[x,y]]/(xy)$ are precisely those $s\in S$ whose expansion $s = s_0 + xF(x) + yG(y)$ has $s_0\in k^\times$. Certainly if $s\in S^\times$, then the image of $s$ in $S/(y) \cong k[[x]]$ must have $s_0\in k^\times$, so $s_0\in k^\times$ is a necessary condition for $s\in S^\times$.

Conversely, suppose $s_0\in k^\times$, then by considering $s_0^{-1}s$, we may assume $s_0 = 1$. Thus, we want to show that any $s\in S$ of the form
$$s = 1 + xF(x) + yG(y)$$
is a unit. To do this, let $xF(x) = \sum_{i\ge 1}f_ix^i$, and $yG(y) = \sum_{i\ge 1}g_iy^i$, and consider the product
$$(1+\sum_{i\ge 1}f_ix^i + \sum_{i\ge 1}g_iy^i)(1 + \sum_{i\ge 1}a_ix^i + \sum_{i\ge 1}b_iy^i)$$
Then the coefficient of $x^n$ in the product is precisely
$$a_n + f_n + \sum_{i,j\ge 1\\ i+j = n}a_if_j$$
and similarly for the coefficient of $y^n$. Thus, by setting the coefficients of $x,y,x^2,y^2,x^3,y^3,\ldots$ to zero, we may inductively solve for the $a_i,b_i$'s such that the resulting product is 1.

Note that this last argument would be substantially trickier (if even possible) if carried out in $R$...

Comment: In the very beginning of your proof, why use $\phi$ instead of the map $R\to R/m_R=k$, which would prove what you want immediately?

Comment: @Mohan Ah, of course! Brilliant. That convinces me that this is right. Thanks!